# is pygame.mixer.music.pause supposed to work in my way?

Tags: python, pygame

I am working on a game written with python 3, pygame. I would like to introduce a feature that the player can press S to pause the game progress (the scene and the music) and press it again to continue.

But I found out pygame.mixer.music.pause() never worked, and because of it, pygame.mixer.music.get_busy() is always True.

stop() works, but I still need pause() so that I can continue from where the music has paused.

Below is the program that I wrote to narrow down the possible range of the problem:

```
import pygame
import random,sys
from pygame.locals import *

''''conclusion: pause() is not working(seems it triggers nothing, and 
as a result, get_busy() is not working with pause() )
'''

# Define some colors
black    = (   0,   0,   0)
white    = ( 255, 255, 255)
red      = ( 255,   0,   0)
blue     = (   0,   0, 255)
purple = (159, 0, 197)

bgColor= (0,   0,   0)
textColor = (250, 250, 255)

width = 600 
height = 600

def end():
    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit()

def drawText(text, font, surface, x, y):
    textobj = font.render(text, 1, textColor)
    textrect = textobj.get_rect()
    textrect.topleft = (x, y)
    surface.blit(textobj, textrect)

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([width,height])

pygame.mixer.music.load('background.mid')  
font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 48)

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

pygame.mixer.music.play(-1, 0.0)
pygame.mixer.music.set_volume(0.5)
paused=False
while True:  #game loop when the game is playing.    
    if not pygame.mixer.music.get_busy(): #is not playing
        print("Not playing")
    for event in pygame.event.get(): 
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: 
            end();       
        elif event.type == KEYUP:    
            if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                end()   
            elif event.key == K_s:    
                print("pause.")
                #pygame.mixer.music.pause() 
                pygame.mixer.music.stop()


    screen.fill(bgColor)
    pygame.display.flip() 
    clock.tick(40)
```

Comment: Why do you need `get_busy()` to return `False`? You could use `if not paused:` and set/unset it on `K_s`. Does the music pause if you call `pygame.mixer.music.pause()`?

Comment: The problem here is that pause() does nothing; the music still plays. According to the pygame document, get_busy() returns True when the music is playing.

Comment: So the issue is `music.pause()` doesn't pause the music. Have you tried to emulate it using `get_pos, stop` to pause and `set_pos, play` to unpause?

Comment: Using get_pos and set_post is a good point. But I find in pygame (maybe only in my installation of pygame and python), set_pos causes an error: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'set_pos'. This is really strange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I tried other format of the background music. I changed the music format from midi to mp3 or ogg, pause() worked. So the problem here is the format.

Also, get_busy() does not do exactly what the pygame document says: pause() and unpause() does not change the return value of get_busy().

Comment: In my game (also using midi format) the music playback is only paused after the end of the file is reached  despite being in an infinite loop. Un-pausing will again start the infinite loop. The value of get_busy did change under these circumstances.